# presentRenderbuffer : GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES takes long time

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I added a profiler to my game and isolated this function. It, sometimes, cause FPS drop. This is my result:

```
Present buffer time: 22
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 9
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 20
Present buffer time: 6
Present buffer time: 4
Present buffer time: 4
Present buffer time: 22
Present buffer time: 4
Present buffer time: 8
Present buffer time: 4
Present buffer time: 4
Present buffer time: 15
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 11
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 6
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 25
Present buffer time: 6
Present buffer time: 7
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 10
Present buffer time: 7
Present buffer time: 3
Present buffer time: 1
Present buffer time: 12
Present buffer time: 9
Present buffer time: 6
Present buffer time: 9
```

Do you know why at every few frames this function takes more time?

This is my code:

```
    f64 time = -System::GetTime();      
    [m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
    Log("Present buffer time: %d\n", u32((System::GetTime() + time) * 1000.));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not calling `glFlush()` explicitly, the driver is forced to do it when you present the buffer, because at the point of `presentRenderbuffer` call the rendering operations on the buffer may not be completed yet.

Try calling `glFlush` before presenting the buffer and measuring time of it separately.

Comment: You are right. If I use glFlush() this functions is executed in constant time(almoust). Do you know why glFlush take different time in different frames? I have same content, but the glFlush time varies from 1ms to 30ms! Thanks for help!

Comment: @Felics. Maybe some other GPU tasks running... Are you working in full-screen mode?

Comment: This code is on iPhone. It's fullscreen and I use opengl in one thread. I added other question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146987/glflush-time-varies-from-frame-to-frame-with-same-content-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

The render buffer presentations that actually go to the display may be being quantized to a 30 Hz or 60 Hz refresh rate.  The fast renders may actually just be throwing away the previous render before the earlier one completes.

Comment: I use display links and limit it to 60 Hz. My update + my render time is around 3 ms(~1 + ~2, simple 2D animation), but my fps is ~50 because of this function and it has drops from time to time to ~30 fps. I had same problem before using display lists, when I used NSTimer. I copied the display list code from a new opengl project template created with xcode. Can you give me more details please?